# how to assign a file name into a variable in shell

Tags: bash, shell, command

How do I assign a command to run a file into a variable.
I have this line:

```
file=$(./file1.sh) #how to properly do this?
if ($0 == $file)
   echo "good to go!"
```

The goal of $file is to check the name of the shell script being run.

file should equal the command you use to run the shell script (ie "./file.sh")

How do I properly do this?

Comment: Hahaha  I think you want to store the value inside the file variable. If so. you can Try "file=$(cat file1.sh)" so that your file variable will have the content of you file1.sh.

If i am wrong or understood something else. Let me know

Comment: Please try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance.

Comment: Something like `if [[ $(basename $0) == file1.sh ]]`? What exactly is the purpose for this? There **are** cases where we want to change the behaviour based on what the invoker did with $0, but they are rare. In most applications, $0 is the name of the script itself, and you usually *do* know this name, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

Close ..

```
file="file1.sh"
if [[ "${0##*/}" == "$file" ]]; then
   echo "good to go!"
fi
```

Comment: I would say `[[ "${0##*/}" == "$file" ]]` to strip directory. (Overthinking? :)

Comment: @tshiono - no, not overthinking; way more robust. :)